# Determine X coordinate of a mouse click

Tags: javascript

I'm making custom controls for html5 video. My problem is occurring when I click on the seek bar. The x coordinates are far off. As I understand, I need to account for all the  margins and padding down to root element, i.e. `myElement<parentOfMyElement<parenOfparentOfMyElement ...` and so on. Every one of them has its own styling with padding and margins and whatnot. How to achieve that without going through entire dom tree backwards?

[image: zero]

I tried:

```
       if(e.target.id==="progress"){

            parent = e.target;
            let x = e.pageX - parent.offsetLeft;
            console.log(x);

        }

        if(e.target.parentNode.id==="progress"){

            parent = e.target.parentNode;
            let x = e.pageX - parent.offsetLeft;
            console.log(x);

        }
```

and other variations. I basically need that when I click on the parent element, get x coord in that element, starting with zero when I click the far left, where the arrow on the image points.

PS: If it's fixed value that's being added up to `x` it wouldn't be a problem, but since resolution gets changed(resize, or in mobile rotate), `x coord` isn't fixed at any given time even when clicking at exact same spot due to previously mentioned.

Edit as per request:

```
            <div id="progress" onClick={this.trackProgress} className="progress text-center">
                <div id="progress-bar-num" className="progress-bar-num">{Math.round(this.state.width.toFixed(2))+"%"}</div>
                <div id="progress-bar" onClick={this.trackProgress} className="progress-bar bg-success" style={{width: Math.round(this.state.width.toFixed(2))+"%"}}></div>
            </div>
```

Don't let my markup confuse you, it is done in React. Effect would be the same if it's done in vanilla js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript get x and y coordinates on mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744605/javascript-get-x-and-y-coordinates-on-mouse-click)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I know how to get coords. Getting isn't hard. Calculating coord inside a parent without going through entire dom tree and testing margins/padding for every element is(tiresome).

Comment: Answers on that question show how to get the page-relative coordinate without calculation...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think the OP want to get coords relative to the seekbar, not the page

Comment: @FZs If that's the case, why would they need to go "through entire dom tree backwards"? Seems like the question is unclear if it's not a duplicate...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey since neither `.pageX` nor `.clientX` take into consideration `padding/margins/border` of every parent and superparent... of said element when calculating click in it.

Comment: But why would you use `pageX` or `clientX` if you only care about the `offsetX`? Why have the click event bound on the parent if you want to know the position of the mouse when clicking in the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're handling the event in a parent of the status bar element, so `.offsetX` is relative to the x position of parent and not the status bar.

Put the event handler on the status bar element itself and the `.offsetX` property of the event will work as you expect.

Comment: I got that function at both elements. Both parent and child element. See edit in a minute.

Comment: Not right answer, but it pointed me at right answer. It is `e.nativeEvent.offsetX`. Since it's React and all ... At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519758/reacts-mouseevent-doesnt-have-offsetx-offsety Accepted your for pointing to right direction. Upped following for saying it's different that vanilla js.